# How to conditional skip html files that don't contain tables in pd.read_html()?

Tags: python, pandas, try-except

I want to iterate over multiple directories that each contain an HTML file on my local machine. I have the paths for each file stored in a list variable but now I want to iterate over each one and read it into something like `pd.read_html` in order to extract table information from the HTML files. However, some files do not contain any tables and therefore throw the error `ValueError: No tables found`. This error is of course expected and I just need help in the logic needed to skip over these.

I've already tried reading over the `pd.DataFrame` (here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and `pd.read_html` (here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_html.html) documentation but I can't find the logic I'm looking for.

This is what I've done so far

```
# initialize the path
p = Path('C:/path/to/directories/')

# glob all html file paths into list of paths
html_paths = [file for file in p.glob('**/*.html')]
```

And so now I have a list of paths I'd like to iterate over and read into `pd.read_html`. I can do this easily with the following code:

```
# initialize empty data frame to append pd.read_html() output to
html_files = pd.DataFrame()

# iterate over each file and read in using pandas
for p in html_paths:
     html_files.append(pd.read_html(str(p)))
```

However, because some of my html files do not contain any tables I get an error when my for loop iterates over those files. I would like a way to skip these files without tables while reading them over so it just keeps on with appending the rest of the files instead of breaking the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do

```
for p in html_paths:
     try:
         html_files = html_files.append(pd.read_html(str(p)))
     except ValueError:
         pass
```

Comment: Alright awesome! This looks like what I'm looking for. I do however end up with an empty data frame when I run this loop? I'm expecting the majority of these files to pass. Is this because each iteration in the loop is overwriting the last?

Comment: @NathanCahn: Close. It's because `append` only returns a new `DataFrame`; it doesn't actually modify `html_files` itself. I've updated the answer accordingly. You might find that performance improves by first gathering all of the individual data frames in a list, then combine them with a single `pd.concat` at the end.

Comment: AH okay, I see. It all work! Thanks so much for your help!